# Sql VS NoSql maintaining a network of friends

Tags: sql, collections, document, nosql

Suppose, a person has multiple friends and each of those friends, further has multiple friends. Consider this as a connection or network of friends.

The SQL way: We maintain a single table of Users and in it, we also keep his/ her list of friends, perhaps as a string with some delimiter.

The NoSql way: Do we maintain the friends list in each documents OR do we maintain a collection for each user.

If we maintain a collection for each user, will it have any impact on speed, because the volume of users can be high.